# Ubuntu freezes when I connnect HTC phone

Tags: usb, 15.10, htc

This only happens once or twice a week. When I insert my HTC E9 Ubuntu will freeze. Shutting down and turning on the computer and plugging the USB usually fixes the problem.

I couldn't find anything on the Internet about this. Here's the related log:

```
Mar 21 20:16:19 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD gnome-session[1150]: (nm-applet:1353): nm-applet-WARNING **: Could not find ShellVersion property on org.gnome.Shell after 5 tries
Mar 21 20:16:21 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD kernel: [   63.692651] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
Mar 21 20:16:21 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD kernel: [   63.822060] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bb4, idProduct=0f25
Mar 21 20:16:21 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD kernel: [   63.822062] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
Mar 21 20:16:21 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD kernel: [   63.822063] usb 1-1: Product: HTC_E9x
Mar 21 20:16:21 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD kernel: [   63.822064] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: MediaTek
Mar 21 20:16:21 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD kernel: [   63.822065] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: LC5AVYP05854
Mar 21 20:16:21 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD kernel: [   63.823204] usb-storage 1-1:1.1: USB Mass Storage device detected
Mar 21 20:16:21 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD kernel: [   63.823281] scsi host7: usb-storage 1-1:1.1
Mar 21 20:16:21 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD org.gtk.Private.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor[1064]: (process:1398): GVFS-GPhoto2-WARNING **: device (null) has no BUSNUM property, ignoring
Mar 21 20:16:21 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD pulseaudio[1241]: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out
Mar 21 20:16:21 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1064]: Device 0 (VID=0bb4 and PID=0f25) is a HTC HTC One M8 (MTP).
Mar 21 20:16:21 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1064]: PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
Mar 21 20:16:21 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1064]: LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
Mar 21 20:16:21 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1064]: inep: usb_get_endpoint_status(): No such device
Mar 21 20:16:21 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1064]: outep: usb_get_endpoint_status(): No such device
Mar 21 20:16:21 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1064]: libusb_open() failed!: No such device
Mar 21 20:16:21 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1064]: LIBMTP PANIC: Could not init USB on second attempt
Mar 21 20:16:21 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1064]: ** (gvfsd:1177): WARNING **: dbus_mount_reply: Error from org.gtk.vfs.Mountable.mount(): Unable to open MTP device '[usb:001,005]'
Mar 21 20:16:21 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD kernel: [   63.913308] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 5
Mar 21 20:16:21 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD gnome-session[1150]: Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Mar 21 20:16:22 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD kernel: [   64.813558] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Mar 21 20:16:22 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD org.gtk.Private.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor[1064]: (process:1398): GVFS-GPhoto2-WARNING **: device (null) has no BUSNUM property, ignoring
Mar 21 20:16:22 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD kernel: [   64.943515] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bb4, idProduct=0f25
Mar 21 20:16:22 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD kernel: [   64.943518] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
Mar 21 20:16:22 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD kernel: [   64.943519] usb 1-1: Product: HTC_E9x
Mar 21 20:16:22 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD kernel: [   64.943520] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: MediaTek
Mar 21 20:16:22 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD kernel: [   64.943521] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: LC5AVYP05854
Mar 21 20:16:22 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD kernel: [   64.949478] usb-storage 1-1:1.1: USB Mass Storage device detected
Mar 21 20:16:22 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD kernel: [   64.949556] scsi host8: usb-storage 1-1:1.1
Mar 21 20:16:22 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD org.gtk.Private.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor[1064]: message repeated 2 times: [ (process:1398): GVFS-GPhoto2-WARNING **: device (null) has no BUSNUM property, ignoring]
Mar 21 20:16:22 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD colord[937]: (colord:937): Cd-WARNING **: CdMain: failed to emit DeviceAdded: failed to register object: An object is already exported for the interface org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Device at /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/sysfs__null_
Mar 21 20:16:22 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1064]: Device 0 (VID=0bb4 and PID=0f25) is a HTC HTC One M8 (MTP).
Mar 21 20:16:23 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD kernel: [   65.946961] scsi 8:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HTC      Android Phone    0310 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Mar 21 20:16:23 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD kernel: [   65.947728] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] scsi-1 drive
Mar 21 20:16:23 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD kernel: [   65.947951] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
Mar 21 20:16:23 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD kernel: [   65.948019] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 5
Mar 21 20:16:23 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD kernel: [   66.112918] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
Mar 21 20:16:23 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD kernel: [   66.117790] ISOFS: changing to secondary root
Mar 21 20:16:23 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD udisksd[1384]: Mounted /dev/sr1 at /media/alex/HTC Sync Manager on behalf of uid 1000
Mar 21 20:16:24 alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine[1064]: ** (zeitgeist-datahub:1633): WARNING **: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:229: Unable to get name "org.gnome.zeitgeist.datahub" on the
```

What could be the problem and how to solve it?

(I think it started happening after a recent Ubuntu update.)

Answer (score 2):

A have the same issue.
When I plug USB from my HTC One M8 to Ubuntu notebook it freezes. No mouse response, no keyboard response. It started about two weeks ago. Worked ok for two years before that.

Partial solution:
When the system is started up with phone already pluged in, it starts ok and phone SD card can be accessed normally.

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Linux kernel: 3.13.0-83-generic

Comment: I'm not alone in the world! Does that happen to you all the time? It only happens to me twice a week ... which is weird.

Comment: At first i did not understand the cause, freeze happened randomly (phone was always connected, reconnections might have been triggered by touching usb cable).
Now it is 100% when phone is getting connected (had two freezes this way, did not inspect any further).

Comment: I see. Weird, I thought 14.04 was a stable release. Or maybe Ubuntu doesn't like HTC (just like nVidia)?

Comment: Same here. Ubuntu 14.04 + HTC One M8

Comment: Here as well. Ubuntu 16.04 HTC One M8. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Update

My phone updated to Android 6.0.1.
Notebook is still on Ubuntu 14.04

Today plugged the phone to Notebook to check if problem is still active. Notebook does not freeze any more.

So for me problem is kind of solved.